# How can the placement of object on focal point produce no image?

Tags: optics, reflection

I have been confused about this question for a while. Like how can the placement of object exactly on focal point of concave produce no image? What is it about placing the object on the focal point itself that reflected rays are caused to not converge and thus not produce image? Also since object is located right at point of focal point, why can't image be superimposed on where the object is, then?

Answer (score 1):

When the object is at the focus the image will be formed at infinity.

As the object gets closer and closer to the focal point, the image gets further and further from the mirror. When the object is between the mirror and the focal point the image is behind the mirror (virtual); when the object further from the mirror than the focal point the image is in front of the mirror (real).

At the focal point the image switches from being at $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.This is the nature of parallel lines. A slight deviation from parallel makes the intersection switch from one side to the other.

If you want the image and object to be at the same place on the optical axis, the object should be located at the centre of curvature. The image will be real and inverted and the same size as the object.

Both cases are illustrated in diagrams at [The Physics Classroom](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-3/Ray-Diagrams-Concave-Mirrors).